# Is it possible to perform an INSERT only through a FUNCTION?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydata
(
  id                            INTEGER NOT NULL,
  datets                        TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  testvalue                     NUMERIC(16,2),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I generated a function to insert data into table `mydata`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DoTest(wid INTEGER, wtestvalue NUMERIC) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mydata (id, datets, testvalue) VALUES (wid, NOW(), wtestvalue);
        RETURN wid;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION DoTest(INTEGER, NUMERIC) FROM PUBLIC;
```

I created a user who can perform the function.

```
CREATE USER internuser PASSWORD '123456' LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOINHERIT NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT 50;

REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE postgres FROM internuser;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION DoTest(INTEGER, NUMERIC) TO internuser;
```

But for the user to execute the function, I need to grant the insert rule to him.

```
GRANT INSERT ON mydata TO internuser;
```

Now the user can perform the function.

```
SELECT DoTest(321, 875465);
```

However, the user can also insert directly into the table.

```
INSERT INTO mydata VALUES (99, '2021-07-18 00:00:00', 123.45);
```

And it is this fact that I want to avoid. That is, I would like the user to only be able to insert data into the table through the function.

Is it possible?

ps. I'm using postgresql 12

Comment: First, `REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE postgres FROM internuser;` is probably not doing what you think it is. See here [Privileges](REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE postgres FROM internuser;) 'Table 5.1. ACL Privilege Abbreviations' for what constitute `DATABASE` privileges.  Also you should not be working in the `postgres` database.  Second, see here [Create Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) for `Security Definer`. In particular section 'Writing SECURITY DEFINER Functions Safely'.

Comment: That should have been [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using SECURITY DEFINER in the function, as suggested by friend Adrian in the comments.